# Automorphism group of a Lorentzian lattice

Tags: nt.number-theory, lattices, automorphism-groups, lorentzian-geometry

Consider the even integral lattices $L_n:=Z\times Z\times Z^{n-2}$ (where $Z$ is the set of integers) with elements $x=(x_+,x_-,x_d)$ and inner product
$$(x,y):=x_+y_-+x_-y_++2x_d\cdot y_d.$$
Its signature is $(-1,n-1)$. For $n>2$, $L_n$ has many vectors of norm $\pm 2$, and the associated reflections are automorphisms, hence $L_n$ has a large automorphism group $G$.

I am interested in a description of $G$ (as explicitly as feasible) and its orbits on vectors of norm $0,\pm 2,\pm 4$, especially for small dimensions $n$ if the general problem is intractable.

Where can I read about the techniques needed to work this out?

[Added 17.10.2023:] Due to the comment of Moische Kohan I checked some papers on hyperbolic reflection groups. In particular, I found the survey

- Belolipetsky, M. (2016). Arithmetic hyperbolic reflection groups.
  Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society, 53(3), 437-475.

which contains many examples and discusses Vinberg's algorithm for finding (in certain cases) the subgroup generated by the reflections (but not the wholeautomorphism group).

Unfortunately, my lattices are not among the examples. Is there a freely available implementation of Vinberg's algorithm?

Comment: This group is the simplest arithmetic lattice in $O(n-1,1)$, in particular, it has finite convolume and is finitely-presentable. Explicit presentation of this group are known in low dimensions but are a mystery in high dimensions.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Please add references so that the presentation will also be known to me!

Comment: Ok, later. If I forget or do not have time: Look at the papers by Vinberg and collaborators where these lattices are described as Coxeter groups.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Thanks; see my update.